# Remove columns which have zero occurrences in a factor level

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have a column of type factor in my data whose summary looks as follows

```
$COL_256
    0     1  <NA>
31557     0     0
```

As you can see, there are only three levels for this column and two of them have zero occurrences, which means it's basically just one factor level.

The trouble with this is that, when I do certain operations like regression, I get an error which says,

```
contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

How can I remove this column which have all their occurrences in just one of the factor levels?

EDIT : I tried droplevels(df) as suggested but now my column looks as follows and gives the same error.

```
$COL_256
    0
31557
```

Comment: Can you show us the exact command you're running that gives that error?

Comment: @bgoldst - any `lm` `glm` etc with a constant will fail, e.g. `lm(y ~ x, data=data.frame(y=1:3,x=letters[c(1)]))`

Answer (score 0):

You could test to see what the status of variables are and drop them if they are constants. E.g.:

```
dat <- data.frame(y=1:3,x=factor("a",levels=c("a","b")),x2=letters[c(1,2,1)])
# y = numeric, x=constant with 2 factor levels, x2=not constant with 2 factor levels

dat[sapply(dat,function(x) length(levels({if(is.factor(x)) droplevels(x) else x}))!=1 )]
#  y x2
#1 1  a
#2 2  b
#3 3  a
```